# Anchored links(" ul li a") when hovering

Tags: html, css, anchor

I'm trying to stop moving objects when hovering.

See what i'm doing here`>`[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0gjo2f38/2/)

When hovering the second link (TEST2), it changes to bold property (need to be), but it pushes the other button (TEST) to the left. How can i anchor other elements in the header and stop their movement?

Comment: Give the list items inline-block display property, and set a width for them that will be larger than the width of the bold text

Comment: Thanks for the advices Lee! (In this comment and others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give an item class to normal list elements and seperator class to seperator list element

```
<div class="header-bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menu-header">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="item"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
          <li class="seperator"><span>&there4;</span></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and give a fixed width to list elements at `.item` class

```
.item {
    width:70px;
}
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bno40ft8/)

Comment: Just to add to this, I would set the actual text items themself to be centre aligned, but make the menu right aligned, as it'll keep the difference between normal and bold, more unified when looking at it.

Comment: Thanks sMr, worked well. The bold still comes from the left, but i think thats a transition error that i made.

Answer (score -1):

give them a fixed width, ie width:80px

Comment: A inline-block would be better, as standard block will put them on separate lines...

Comment: of course you need to add a floating to display:blokc in order to see them inline, but it was not the OP question

Comment: So why would you tell him to make them display:block, and then float them left, when if you look in his original code, they're already inline-block?